# Renaming files with the same name when moving them

Tags: bash, shell-script, mv

This is my current code:

```
Base_DIR=/file/path
other= /folder/path
find "Base_DIR" -type f -name "*.txt"
while IFS= read -r file; do
year="$(date -d "$(stat -c %y "$file")" +%Y
month="$(date -d "$(stat -c %y "$file")" +%m
day="$(date -d "$(stat -c %y "$file")" +%d

[[ ! -d "$other/$year/$month/$day" ]] && mkdir -p "$other/$year/$month/$day";

mv "$file" "$other/$year/$month/$day`
```

So it basically finds the files from different sub-directories and moves the file into a different folder while creating a folder depending on the year, month and day of when the file was last modified.

My question is how can i add to this so when i move files with the same name it will automatically rename the file to, for example file(1).txt. Right now the code only copies 1 of the files and not both.

Thank you.

Comment: The current code does not work. You have multiple errors in it, including spaces after a `=` and no `done` at the end of the loop. You're presumably wanting to pipe the result of the `find` command into the loop, right?  You also seem to miss `$` on `$Base_DIR`.

Comment: install and use `shellcheck`.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
mv --backup=t file directory/
```

You should get files named file, file.~1~, file.~2~, etc.

Comment: Great! this works!

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding that the code in your question does not work at all, to address the question of "how can I nondestructively move a file by adding a numerical suffix", something akin to this might work:

```
$ cat mvr.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

bail() {
   retcode=$1
   shift
   printf "%s" "$*" 1>&2
   exit "$retcode"
}

[[ -f "$1" ]] || bail 1 "File '$1' not found"

if ! [[ -f "$2" ]]; then
   mv "$1" "$2"
else
   if [[ -d "$2" ]]; then
      $0 "$1" "${2}/${1}"
      exit $?
   else
      suffix=1
      until ! [[ -f "${2}.$suffix" ]]; do
         suffix=$((suffix+1))
      done
      mv "$1" "${2}.$suffix"
   fi
fi
```

In action:

```
$ ls
bar    bar.1  bar.2  mvr.sh
$ touch foo; ls
bar    bar.1  bar.2  foo    mvr.sh
$ ./mvr.sh foo bar
$ ls
bar    bar.1  bar.2  bar.3  mvr.sh
```

The real meat of how do do this starts at the `if` statement.

- If the destination filename doesn't yet exist, great, just `mv`.
- If it exists and is a directory, great: write into that directory by recursing.
- If it exists and is a file, start trying new numerical suffixes until we find one that's not already present.